# I found an incorrect translation in Bitcoin Core, how can I suggest a fix?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

In the French version of the Bitcoin Core (v26), a column in the peer tab is called "Age" which means age. It is wrong because Bitcoin Core is using peer which have no age, it is not as people age.
It should be called duration, so in French "Durée".

[image]

How would I go about getting this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

To answer "How to contribute to translations for Bitcoin Core?"

Bitcoin Core translations are handled by an open source project called Transifex: https://www.transifex.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/ To add your fix create an account to Transifex, you can edit the translations on the web interface. Though be warned that it looks like the French translations are only accepted from the French team which might require you an application. You can also message in the web app the French team coordinators to suggest your edit.

Comment: Thank you Juha and Murch for answers/corrections.
There is no role for people who have a node on Transifex. 
Furthermore, it was just a detail.